# Assembly's App.Config is being ignored; Machine.config being read instead

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, configuration, app-config

In running my VS2008 <strike>unit</strike> integration tests against my DAL, I have found that the assembly is reading `machine.config` instead of the assembly's `app.config`.

Here's the rundown on the call stack:

- Unit Test Project has method calling into a DataLayer Project
- `MyDataLayer` class inherits from a base class. Method is called `GetStuff()`
- Base class is using `System.Configuration` . All good.
- calling this property in code: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnStr"]` actually returns null because it's not found apparently.
- checking the  `MyDataLayer` class, yep, MyConnStr is there.
- checking the collection `ConnectionStrings`, yes, it has one connection string. It's the one in machine.config that's over in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\machine.config`
- I am not sure why my DAL's `app.config` is being superseded by the `machine.config`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this applies to you, but you need to make sure the configuration string is in your Unit Test Project's app.config, not your DataLayer project.

Comment: Ray, you're a monster! All I had to do was reference System.Configuration and copy/share the App.Config from the DataLayer project over to my UnitTest project, and it worked. Bravo!

Answer (score 2):

This might help to some people dealing with `Settings.settings` and `App.config`:

Watch out for `GenerateDefaultValueInCod`e attribute in the Properties pane while editing any of the value (rows) in the Settings.settings grid in Visual Studio (VS2008 in my case).

If you set `GenerateDefaultValueInCode` to True (True is the default here!), the default value is compiled into the exe (or dll), you can find it embedded in the file when you open it in a plain text editor.

I was working on a console application and if I had defaults in the exe, the application always ignored the config file placed in the same directory!

Quite a nightmare and no information about this on the whole internet.